# React/Typescript : this.setState is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, setstate

I am work in react + typescript for first time.

```
interface IState {
  stateval: number;
}
class Forgotpassword extends React.Component<any, IState> {
  constructor(props: any){
    super(props);
    this.state = { stateval: 1 };
  }
  public submit() {  
    this.setState({ stateval:2 });
  }
  public render() {
    const { stateval} = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Button onClick={this.submit}>Send OTP</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When i click the submit button it throws

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function
```

Comment: add `this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);` to your constructor.

Comment: `<Button onClick={() => this.submit}>Send OTP</Button>` or  `public submit = () => {  
    this.setState({ stateval:2 });
  }`

Comment: the `this` context of the button, is the button. you need to bind the submit function to the ForgotPassword class

Comment: Whether bind function calls or use arrow functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to bind your method or trasform in functional like

```
interface IState {
  stateval: number;
}
class Forgotpassword extends React.Component<any, IState> {
  constructor(props: any){
    super(props);
    this.state = { stateval: 1 };
  }
  const submit = () => {  
    this.setState({ stateval:2 });
  }
  const render = () => {
    const { stateval} = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Button onClick={this.submit}>Send OTP</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

i hope it useful

Comment: is there a way to print object, since JSON.stringify() & conssole.log() is not working in typescript

Comment: try to print a simple string first, console.log("Hi") if it work, console.log it's ok, it have to work

Comment: worked after adding rule    "no-console": false   in  tslint.json file, thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to add the constructor method or use bind. An arrow function is fine for your needs.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

interface IState {
  stateval: number;
}

export default class Forgotpassword extends Component<any, IState> {
  state = {
    stateval: 2
  }

  public submit = () => this.setState({ stateval: 2 });

  public render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Button onClick={this.submit}>Send OTP</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please bind your submit function to this :

this.submit = this.submit.bind(this)